# subtract dict item from column, using another column as lookup key in dict

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` and a dictionary `dic`.

I want to use the value in one column of my dataframe to look up an entry in a dictionary, and subtract the returned value from another column

```
df.time - dic[df.weekday]
```

This fails with the following error:

> ```
> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
> ```

**Details:**

I have a DataFrame with two columns, `weekday` and `time`:

[image]

I have a dictionary of `weekday` to `time`:

```
times:

{'Mon': datetime.time(18, 0),
 'Tue': datetime.time(18, 0),
 'Wed': datetime.time(18, 0),
 'Thu': datetime.time(18, 0),
 'Fri': datetime.time(18, 0),
 'Sat': None,
 'Sun': datetime.time(19, 0)}
```

I would like to add a 3rd column to my dataframe which is the `timedelta` between each row's `time` and the corresponding entry in the dictionary.

**Questions:**

- How can I use one column's value to lookup a dictionary entry and subtract the returned value from another column?
- Some rows have `None` in them, how can I account for these and return a special value (eg `None` or some other special value)?

Comment: I think you just need `df.time - df.weekday.map(dic)`.

Comment: @jdehesa thanks, that was quick! Is there a way to account for the fact some rows have `None` in them, and therefore need special casing?

Comment: Can't you add `None: special_value` to `dic`? (I'm not sure if you mean the value `None` or the string `'None'`, but I think either should work)

Comment: @jdehesa it's that sometimes there is a `None` in the column instead of a time, which results in `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.time'`

Comment: Ah right, sorry, you mean in the `time` column. Well you could replace all `None` values with `pd.NaT`, that should allow you to operate and just get `NaT` as a result (also for `Sat` in the dictionary).

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks, I'll try that out!